# Snowflake database organization when you have multiple environments (dev/test/prod)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am considering 2 methods to organize my `snowflake databases`, and would like to get some opinions from the `snowflake architecture` masters out there.  To me, Design 1 is better due to code portability across environments.  Which is better?

***Design 1*:-**

**Separation of usage by schemas:**

This first design allows for code portability across environments, without the need to reference database names in code between environments.  Cloning also works well here.  The downside here is that schemas (not databases) are the only separation of data usage.  Unfortunately, `snowflake` does not support synonyms (aliases) which would allow me to use Design 2, with full code portability.

**Data_Lake_Dev**

> schemas as needed for raw, base, transformed (Sales, Mkt, etc), and dimensional marts

**Data_Lake_Test**

> schemas as needed for raw, base, transformed, and dimensional marts

**Data_Lake_Prod**

> schemas as needed for raw, base, transformed, and dimension marts

***Design 2:***

**Separation of usage by Databases:**

This second design creates databases for separation of usage, which is much clearer then Design 1, but code is not portable across environments (except when using Dbt, which allows this via jinga code, creating aliases across dbs).  In the below, you would repeat each, for _dev, _test, and _prod environments, so 12 databases vs 3 in the first design.

**Raw_db_dev**

> raw ingestion

**Base_db_dev**

> light transforms

**Transform_db_Dev**

> Business area usage (Sales, Marketing, etc)

Analytics_db_Dev (data marts)

Comment: Use separate Snowflake accounts for Dev, Test, Prod. Then all objects have the same name regardless of which environment they are in - which make code control, deployment, etc. much easier

Comment: Is the design one single database per all enviroment? If yest then alternative is using DB_DEV(schema1/schema2/schema3) , DB_TEST(schema1/schem2/schema2) , DB_PROD(schema1/schem2/schema3) is possible. No cross-database references, and each object should use only two-part names - code is portable as it is contained inside single DB. Then during deployment it is a matter of connecting to correct database.

Comment: Nick - I like the idea of separate accounts, but now sure how you can clone across accounts.  Many times, on a schedule, or on demand, test is cloned from prod so that testing is on the freshest data.

Comment: Lukasz - Yes, design 1 is one database per environment.  If snowflake implemented synonyms (aliases), then I would go with Design 2, as it allows for better separation of data usage without losing code portability.  Ex. This would make it possible for a base_dev view to reference a raw_dev table, by setting an an alias to reference the dev database when in dev.

Comment: Instead of cloning you can share/replicate to other accounts. Obviously your situation may differ from mine, but in the regulated industries I work in and with enterprise scale clients, separation of Prod and non-Prod is mandatory and under no circumstances would it be allowed to clone Prod data to a non-Prod environment - and separating Prod and non-Prod into different accounts helps to ensure this

Comment: Nick - thanks, sounds like different accounts is the only choice for compliance in regulated industries.  Unless you see otherwise ,that solves the single code base issue, and I can separate my databases (raw, stg, transform, mart) in a single account = good.  However, how do you get your dev or test accounts refreshed with "fresh" production quality data?  Replication and sharing are read-only replicas, and thus do not support development.

Comment: @DavidDumas I think Nick means you can replicate data prod -> dev and then clone objects from the replica into your dev databases.

Comment: In theory you can replicate/share and then clone/insert overwrite. However, in my world this is not so simple given that we cannot have Prod data in a non-Prod environment - so there is a need to obfuscate all PII and financial information

Comment: How about Design 3: separate databases for dev, test, and prod, and then use schemas for all of your layers (raw, etc.) and subject areas (base, analytics, etc.).  So, database called `PROD`, schemas called `base_raw`, `analytics_raw`, etc.  This separates environments at the database level, and no code would ever need to reference a database.  This also still allows you to CLONE, which I think is one of the bigger benefits of Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

David - according to me, Code portability should not be a decision maker at all for organizing your snowflake databases. Snowsql provides variables/parameterization options. Follow the below link to overcome the issue related to code migration across multiple databases/envs/accounts.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#using-variables

I'd personally prefer having 2 separate accounts - 1 for DEV/QA and another for Prod.

Comment: I agree, separate accounts is better from a compliance and disaster recovery standpoint.  I brought that up, but unfortunately that was voted down for complexity reasons.  So, I will have to separate by dev/test/prod as separate databases in the same account (design 1).  I still get the benefits of a common code base.